# Shunting-yard algorithm - proof

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof

How can one prove that a shunting-yard algorithm always returns a correct expression in RPN? I cannot find any proof in the internet.

Answer (score 4):

The shunting-yard algorithm was introduced in Dijkstra's article *Making a Translator for ALGOL-60* (APIC Bulletin no7, 1961; see this [PDF](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/MCReps/MR35.PDF), from p.22; also published in *Annual Review in Automatic Programming*, 7:3–11, 1963 and [available from Science Direct](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0066-4138(63)80016-6) if your institution has a subscription).  Pages 7–9 of the article (pp.28–30 of the PDF) explain how the algorithm works and argue its correctness. It's not a formal proof but it looks like it contains everything you should need to produce one.